# Не верно выводится дата из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Вывожу данные из таблицы таким запросом?

```
SELECT 
                        from_login,
                        from_open_key, 
                        encrypt_by_from_key, 
                        who_login, 
                        who_open_key, 
                        encrypt_by_who_key, 
                        date_time 
                    FROM Messages 
                    WHERE 
                        from_login = 'u9' AND 
                        who_login='user2' AND 
                        date_time < '2016-09-05 22:47:28' 
            UNION 
                    SELECT from_login, 
                        from_open_key, 
                        encrypt_by_from_key, 
                        who_login, 
                        who_open_key, 
                        encrypt_by_who_key, 
                        date_time 
                    FROM Messages 
                    WHERE 
                        from_login = 'user2' AND 
                        who_login='u9' AND 
                        date_time < '2016-09-05 22:47:28' 
                    ORDER BY date_time 
                    ASC LIMIT 10
```

Таблица иемет такой вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что при выполнении запроса теряются строки имеющие такие значения времени:

2016-09-05 22:47:19
2016-09-05 22:47:22
2016-09-05 22:47:24

Почему они теряются?

Comment: может быть из-за ограничения в 10 строк? ASC LIMIT 10

Comment: Нет всё так же пропадают записи

Comment: И кстати, может упростите запрос, зачем этот union, достаточно одной выборки по условию `where date_time < '2016-09-05 22:47:28'  and ( (from_login = 'u9' AND who_login='user2') or (from_login = 'user2' AND who_login='u9') )`. Хотя записи от этого конечно не появятся. А почему могут не попадать даже не представляю. Пример бы на sqlfiddle сделали, так что бы в нем была та же проблема ...